# Visualizar un formulario dinámico html con Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, formularios, bucles

Tengo un modelo llamado Caso y otro llamado Secuencia, estos estan relacionados ya que cada caso puede tener varias secuencias; en una vista me gustaria mostrar un formulario o un recuadro de opciones de respuesta para el usuario, es decir, al usuario se le muestra un caso y sus secuencias y el usuario pone los datos necesarios de esas secuencias. En el controlador de Caso llamo a las secuencias relacionadas con el caso en cuestión, pero no sé como mostrar en la vista el formulario con todas las secuencias. al principio lo hice con un @foreach y debajo puse la info del form y así me creaba un form para cada secuencia, pero el id del form seguia siendo el mismo, entonces descartaría esa opción, pero ahora no sé qué podría cambiar de mi código.

Mi vista esta así:

```
<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform" action="/validacion" method="POST">
@csrf
<!-- progressbar -->
<ul id="progressbar">
  <li class="active">Secuencias</li>
  <li>Te / Tr / Ti</li>
  <li>Detalles extra</li> 
</ul>
<!-- fieldsets -->
<fieldset>
   <h2 class="fs-title">{{ $caso->dx }}</h2>
   <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Protocolo: {{ $caso->protocolo }}</h3>
   <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Secuencia: {{ $secuencias->nombre }}</h3>
   <input type="text" name="plano" placeholder="Plano" />
   <input type="text" name="tipoSecuencia" placeholder="Tipo de Secuencia" />
   <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Siguiente" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
   <h2 class="fs-title">{{ $caso->dx }}</h2>
   <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Protocolo: {{ $caso->protocolo }}</h3>
   <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Secuencia: {{ $secuencias->nombre }}</h3>
   <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Te </h3>
   <select class="select" name="te" id="te"
      <option value="1,2">1,2</option>
      <option value="1,5">1,5</option>
      <option value="1,45">1,45</option>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
   <h2 class="fs-title">{{ $caso->dx }}</h2>
   <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Protocolo: {{ $caso->protocolo }}</h3>
   <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Secuencia: {{ $secuencias->nombre }}</h3>
   <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Grosor de corte: {{ $secuencias->grosor_corte }} </h3>
   <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Campo de visión: {{ $secuencias->campo_vision }} </h3>
   <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Matriz: {{ $secuencias->matriz }}</h3>
   <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Adquisiciones: {{ $secuencias->adquisiciones }} </h3>
   <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Dirección de Fase: {{ $secuencias->direccion_fase }}</h3>
   <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Anterior" />
   <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Finalizar" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Y la funcion del controlador:

```
public function store(Request $request, Secuencia $secuencia)
{
    $casoDiagnostico = $request->caso;
    $caso = Caso::find($casoDiagnostico);
    $secuencias = Secuencia::all()->where('caso_id' , '=' , $casoDiagnostico);
    return view('Practicas.respuesta', compact('caso', 'secuencias'));
}
```

El request tiene el id del caso (que lo obtiene de otra vista) por eso cuando llamo a secuencia pongo que donde caso_id sea igual al id del caso y paso a la vista con estos datos.
Sin embargo no entiendo muy bien como mostrar ese form dinámico ya que unos casos tiene 3 secuencias, otros 6 etc...además de mostrar cada info de las secuencias (ya que cada secuencia tiene su informacion propia)
gracias de antemano.

Otra cosa para agregar, al poner un foreach al inicio de cada fieldset me gusta como lo muestra en la vista:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al poner datos en los input, y hacer dd de lo que manda el form solo guarda lo ultimo que puse:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

yo te aconsejaria usaras la herencia del motor de plantillas blade, que usa laravel.

declaras un archivo padre con con los campos en comun de todas las secuencias y para cada secuencia un archivo blade con su correspondiente codigo. Heredas en cada uno de estos de la platilla padre. En la vista que realmente cargas desde el controlador declaras el foreach y preguntas cual tipo de secuencia estas iterando(puede ser un switch), e incluyes el archivo blade que determines para ese tipo de secuencia.

Incluso para ahorrarte la pregunta declaras el nombre de cada archivo blade igual a un  campo que se refleje en la tabla de secuencia de la base de datos y que sea unico, por ejemplo nombre de la secuecia y ya el include dentro del foreach lo haces directamente usando este campo que va a corresponder con el nombre del archivo blade de la secuencia correspondiente.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, sin embargo si hiciera un archivo blade para cada secuencia me llevaria mucho, ya que por ejemplo, el caso 1 tiene de secuencia t2 y ese t2 tiene un campo de vision de 3.5...el caso 2 tambien tiene secuencia t2 pero ese tiene campo de vision 4.1...por lo que cada secuencia es diferente

Comment: pensé en una sola vista donde el usuario escogiera la secuencia en un select y pusiera los datos de esa secuencia, enviara la respuesta del formulario al controlador para validarlo y si es correcto, regrese a esa misma vista y ahora el usuario en ese select seleccione la siguiente secuencia y asi sucesivamente hasta finalizar con todas las secuencias, pero no sé que tan eficiente sea eso o si realmente es lo correcto...

Comment: la vista que publicas es la de un caso que tiene x secuencias?. segun entiendo son muchas las posibilidades en la que un caso puede deferenciar a otro en cuanto al numero de secuencias? Te comento lo de las platillas blade porque por ejemplo la interfaz de las dos primeras secuencias se pueden cargan con el mismo archivo blade, no necesitas declarar 2 veces el codigo comun.

Comment: para definir el diseño mas adecuado para tu caso hay que conocer mejor el negocio con sus limitantes y posiblidades, pero enviar el formulario para guardar  cada vez que se registra una secuencia no es una buena opcion. puedes usar ajax pero igual es preferible validar en el cliente siempre que sea posible y enviar el formulario con todas sus secuencias de una vez y te encargas de validar en el servidor tambien.En cuanto al form recuerda que todo lo que declares dentro del form con su etiqueta name se envia, sino no lo recibes puede ser que dos campos tengan en mismo name.